# dmcrypt : What happens when userspace crypto wrapper not present?

Tags: linux, encryption, arm

I am trying to set up an encrypted volume to store files securely. This is done on a NextThingCo pocketchip, but the OS is based on debian so I guessed I would give it a try here first, as my question is more related to dmcrypt than the platform itself (or so I think).

The recipe that I built so far is the following (may be incorrect or overly complicated):

1. Create a file
2. Set it up as a loop device.
3. Do the crypsetup for formatting and open. "abc" is the password, fed through stdin (is this assumption correct?).
4. Make a filesystem
5. Mount

So it looks like this:

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=./encrypted.volume bs=512K count=200
 sudo losetup /dev/loop0 ./encrypted.volume  
 echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop0
 echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup open /dev/loop0 vault
 sudo mkfs /dev/mapper/vault
 sudo mount /dev/mapper/vault /mnt/vault
```

Now, all this seems to work fine and dandy, that is until I used the --debug parameter (I wanted to try other parameters as well e.g. key-size). And I realized the following messages:

```
# cryptsetup 1.7.0 processing "cryptsetup -v --debug --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 
512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000 --timeout 10 --use-random luksFormat /dev/loop0"
# Running command luksFormat.
...
# Userspace crypto wrapper cannot use aes-xts-plain64 (-95).
...
device-mapper: remove ioctl on temporary-cryptsetup-6661 failed: Device or resource busy    <------ appears when I change the  --key-size to 512 i.s.o. default 256
...
device-mapper: remove ioctl on temporary-cryptsetup-6698 failed: Device or resource busy
```

I tried running the benchmark too:

```
chip@chip:~/data/run$ sudo cryptsetup --debug benchmark
[sudo] password for chip:
# cryptsetup 1.7.0 processing "cryptsetup --debug benchmark"
# Running command benchmark.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.6.4) initialized in cryptsetup library version 1.7.0.
# Detected kernel Linux 4.4.13-ntc-mlc armv7l.
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha1: 59041 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-sha1        59041 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha256: 79437 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-sha256      79437 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha512: 40705 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-sha512      40705 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash ripemd160: 50412 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-ripemd160   50412 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash whirlpool: 7481 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-whirlpool    7481 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# Cannot initialise cipher aes, mode cbc.
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Command failed with code 95: Operation not supported
```

Here is some additional info about the platform and OS:

```
chip@chip:~/data/run$ uname -r
4.4.13-ntc-mlc
chip@chip:~/data/run$ cat /boot/config-4.4.13-ntc-mlc | grep CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER
# CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER is not set
```

I understand that I would need to recompile the kernel after I set CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER so the userspace crypto API becomes available. I don't think there is a way around that, is there?

I LuksDump the information about the storage file:

```
chip@chip:~/data/run$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump ./encrypted.volume

LUKS header information for ./encrypted.volume

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes          <------- ???
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64  <------- ???
Hash spec:      sha256       
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      ee f8 8d ad 9b 67 d9 7d cb 20 fe a9 25 a3 8b a5 c2 65 56 dd
MK salt:        38 74 e8 9d 77 6a 93 b5 03 41 cb 3e ce 79 b4 00
                55 f3 98 8f c5 a7 14 05 25 9c 4e 91 68 1a 53 37
MK iterations:  18500
UUID:           36912ea4-9adb-4d1f-b9f2-f6a09a258833

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
        Iterations:             150587
        Salt:                   e8 4f f3 c1 07 1a 2b 2d d2 d9 f4 55 0f b3 13 28
                                2a 69 06 aa a0 94 4a 05 5d 5f e9 28 9b 91 39 94
        Key material offset:    8
        AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

However, I have a few questions about the current situation:

- Is the partition actually encrypted? If so, with which scheme?

  - How to check this on the command line? Trying to dump information about the partition tells me that "there is a LUKS header", but that does not tell me whether the data is encrypted or not.
- How to solve the ''resource busy'' situation, which would let me use a key size of 512?

Thank you for reading all the way here. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to be right, after I read the given link. I have moved the question to Super User. What should I do about this post?